# How to get all url's ( not just titles ) in a wikipedia article using mediawiki api?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am using the wikimedia api to retrieve all possible URL's from a wikipedia article ,'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&redirects&pllimit=500&format=json' , but it is only giving a list of link titles , for example , Artificial Intelligence , wikipedia page has a link titled " delivery networks," , but the actual URL is "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network" , which is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generator:

[`action=query&
 format=jsonfm&
 titles=Estelle_Morris&
 redirects&
 generator=links&
 gpllimit=500&
 prop=info&
 inprop=url`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&redirects&gpllimit=500&format=jsonfm&titles=Estelle_Morris&prop=info&inprop=url)

See API docs on [generators](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) and [the `info` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info).

Comment: This is short and simply , I never though it was directly possible with API , I will go through generator and info module in detail , Thanks!

Comment: How we can get a list of all the links available under the 'See Also' section?

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced most of my previous answer, including the code, to use the information provided in Tgr's answer, in case someone else would like sample Python code. This code is heavily based on code from Mediawiki for so-called 'raw continuations'.

I have deliberately limited the number of links requested per invocation to five so that one more parameter possibility could be demonstrated.

```
import requests

def query(request):
    request['action'] = 'query'
    request['format'] = 'json'
    request['prop'] = 'info'
    request['generator'] = 'links'
    request['inprop'] = 'url'
    previousContinue = {}
    while True:
        req = request.copy()
        req.update(previousContinue)
        result = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', params=req).json()
        if 'error' in result:
            raise Error(result['error'])
        if 'warnings' in result:
            print(result['warnings'])
        if 'query' in result:
            yield result['query']
        if 'continue' in result:
            previousContinue = {'gplcontinue': result['continue']['gplcontinue']}
        else:
            break

count = 0        
for result in query({'titles': 'Estelle Morris', 'gpllimit': '5'}):
    for url in [_['fullurl'] for _ in list(result.values())[0].values()]:
        print (url)
```

I mentioned in my first answer that, if the OP wanted to do something similar with artificial intelligence then he should begin with 'Artificial intelligence' — noting the capitalisation. Otherwise the search would start with a disambiguation page and all of the complications that could arise with those.

Comment: Thank you for providing code  and effort , I will go through the code :)

Comment: I should have credited a page on mediawiki for much or most of the idea for this code: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query.